# How can I get my question reopened as someone answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I posted the following question on programmers.stackexchange.com : [Is there any language-agnostic specification for "String Natural Sorting Order"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257286/is-there-any-language-agnostic-specification-for-string-natural-sorting-order)

I posted it on programmers.stackexchange.com as the description of the website says it is for "conceptual questions" vs SO being for "on the spot answers".

Unfortunately instead of being positively welcomed it was quickly **closed because "opinion-based"**.

The good part is that closing a question "only" stops people from posting an **answer**, not to comment on the actually question.

**In the end, somebody did find an on-the-spot answer & posted it in the comments**, see the comment from Bart van Ingen Schenau on Sep 29 at 10:35.

Now I have to say this is not the first time that I get users tag my question as "opinion-based" or "not constructive". And it really starts to annoy me as I get the feeling that many users tend to do that "only" because they do not know the answer of the question AND on top of that these users would not even advise the person who posted the question on where would be a more appropriate place to put the question, or how the question could be improved.

Finally, can someone reopen my question so that the answer from Bart van Ingen Schenau can be marked as an answer? sigh....

Comment: Done. Anything else I can help you with?

Comment: Thanks. Nope, eeeeh actually if you can give me the super power of slapping people through their computer screen that'd be great

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a moderator only feature.

Comment: I now understand why you guys decided to become moderators ^^

Comment: Moderation on this site is basically a cesspool.

Comment: @AdrienBe [Punch a user button](http://stackapps.com/questions/3802/punch-a-user-button).  'Tis only a placebo, unfortunately

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are three things you can, and should, do:

1. Edit the question. Remove any ambiguity, add extra details, fix the spelling and grammar, etc. Generally improve it. This will add the question to the Reopen Review queue where it will get reviewed and, if you've made sufficient edits, reopened.
2. Post a request in your site's chat room (in this case [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)). Make a convincing argument.
3. Raise a question on the site's on child meta (in this case [Meta Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com)). Make a convincing argument so enough people vote to reopen.

Comment: Does this mean that flagging the question with a custom reason of "I think this question should be reopened because X" is not appropriate?

Comment: @svick - as I said you should be editing or using chat and/or meta to gain the support of four other users rather than asking a mod to do it. A mod may well cast a binding reopen vote in response, but that shouldn't be assumed. Moderators are not here to do for you what you can do yourself.